# Is this the best way to define new preamble commands and restructure the already defined ones?

Tags: preamble, variable

I have a latex class that extends the AMS article class `amsart`. I have adjusted the margins and wanted to add a few new preamble styled parameters like `\author{Name}`, e. g., `\class{Algebra}`. After doing so, I wanted the author name, class, date and the title to appear like this when `\maketitle` is called. Note that in case one of these is not provided, I want that to result in the lack of that field and **not** a crash. For example, if the preamble does not have `\class{...}` then there should be only student name and the date in the document. If neither the student name, class name and date are provided then the document should start with a centred title.

```
Student Name
Algebra
Decembruary 3, 1947
                                Centred Title
                                       .
                                       .
                                       .
```

Here is what I put together,

```latex
% this handles the info tags at the beginning
\makeatletter
   % defining new variables
   \gdef\@class{\empty}
   \def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1\\}}
   \def\class#1{\gdef\@class{#1\\}}
    \renewcommand{\maketitle} {
      \bgroup
        \setlength{\parindent}{0em}
          \begin{flushleft}
            \ifx\@author\empty \else \@author\fi
            \ifx\@class\empty \else \@class\fi
            \@date
          \end{flushleft}
      \egroup
      \begin{center}
        \textbf{\@title} \\
      \end{center}
      \bigskip
    }
\makeatother
```

Honestly, I have no idea how or why this code works because I started with something and proceeded with trial and error till something kinda worked. Which is why, I have reason to believe that this might not be the cleanest or best way of accomplishing what I want. Could someone who actually understands programming in latex have a look and maybe tell how I could write this better or what I have is good enough?

Comment: The first rule of programming. If it works don't touch.

Comment: The issue is sometimes when I am using this class with org-mode, I randomly get weird behaviour and I can't pin down what causes it. I also want to one day publish my class in an official repository so I want to make sure that I am not doing something stupid that oughta be done some other way.

Comment: To me there are nothing wrong in your code, although sincerely, I see no advantage of redefine `\maketitle` in this way over simply  type 
 `John Doe\par Algebra\par \today  \section*{The Title}`